# Integration of SVN Repository server with Jenkins for CI/CD Pipeline deployment

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline concept in my microservice oriented architecture. I have a on-Premise SVN repository server. And it contains the spring boot code repo. I need to implement here CI/CD concept. When I am committing the modified codes then need to compile and test by automation tool Jenkins. This is my requirement.

Everywhere I am reading that Jenkins integration with Github codes. But here I want to release my code from SVN repository to Jenkins.

How can I integrate my SVN repository with Jenkins automation tool? And also are there any implementation documentation or tutorials to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you are using Jenkins jobs or Jenkins pipelines. Assuming you are using jobs, you can install SVN plugins which enables your job to checkout code from SVN, just like how you clone repository from git.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

After installing the plugin, you get the option of SVN/Subversion under Source Code Managment

[image]

Comment: Ok. I just started the exploration of how to work with jenkins. I am trying to use kubernetes aslo. When I am reading only seeing integration with github. So now trying to use SVN with jenkins. Anyway thank you for your response sir.